# GET request into table

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have this next html document, which has to load a table, which is filled with the values I get back from a XMLHttpRequest.

when I try to run the page, it won't give anything like a table back, so if anyone sees what's the problem in this code, please help!!

```
<!doctype html>

<html class="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Evenementen | Sociale buurt</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="onzebuurt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
        initialiseListEvenementen();
};  

initialiseListEvenementen() {
    var BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/OnzeBuurt2/resources/";

    var events = [];
    //load the groups from the back-end
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", BASE_URL + "events");
    request.onload = function() {
        if(request.status === 200) {
            events = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                $("#eventList").append(createListElementForEvent(i));
            }
            if(events.length > 0) {
                $("#eventList").listview('refresh');
            } else {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Error loading groups: " + request.status + " - "+ request.statusText);
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
}

function createListElementForEvent(eventIndex) {

    var datum = $("<p>").text("Datum: " + events[eventIndex].datum);
    var titel = $("<p>").text("Titel: " + events[eventIndex].titel);
    var details = $("<p>").text("Details: " + events[eventIndex].details);
    var auteur = $("<p>").text("auteur: " + events[eventIndex].auteur.naam);
    var latitude = $("<p>").text("Datum: " + events[eventIndex].locatie.latitude);
    var longitude = $("<p>").text("Datum: " + events[eventIndex].locatie.longitude);

    return $("<li>").append(datum).append(titel).append(details).append(auteur).append(latitude).append(longitude);
}

</script>

</head>
<body class="body2">
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div class="header2">
        <center>
        Evenementen
        </center>
  </div>

    <ul id="eventList" class="lijst"></ul>

        <div id="home2">
            <form name="input" action="" method="get">
                <a href="welkom.html"><img src="home.png" alt="Home" /></a>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="terug2">
            <form name="input" action="" method="get">
                <a href="bekijken.html"><img id="btnterug" src="vorige.png" alt="Vorige" /></a>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What *do* you get back?

Comment: I only get back my page with it's css.
everything !! exept !! 

<ul id="eventList" class="lijst"></ul>

get's back

Comment: I don't understand why you are using plain xmlhttprequest when you are using jquery, your code will not work in IE

Comment: @KevinBaeyens I advise you to post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, so as to help others find this answer, and also so we know it's been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after couple of hours of work, I found the solution. Hope i can help some of you:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html class="">

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Evenementen | Sociale buurt</title>
 <link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="onzebuurt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var url = "http://localhost:8080/OnzeBuurt2/resources/events";
 var events = [];

 $(document).ready(function() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url);
  request.onload = function() {
   if(request.status === 200) {
                                events = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
     $("#eventList").append(createListElementForEvent(i));
    }
                                if(events.length > 0) {
     $("#eventList").listview('refresh');
    } else {
     console.log("Error");
    }
   } else {
   alert("fout gegaan");
            console.log("Error loading groups: " + request.status + " - "+ request.statusText);
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
    });

    function createListElementForEvent(eventIndex) {

  var datum = $("<td>").text(events[eventIndex].datum);
  var titel = $("<td>").text(events[eventIndex].titel + " - " + events[eventIndex].details);
  var auteur = $("<td>").text(events[eventIndex].auteur.naam);

  return $("<tr>").append(datum).append(titel).append(auteur);
 } 
 </script>

 </head>
 <body class="body2">
 <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
   <div class="header2">
   <center>
   Evenementen
   </center>
   </div>
 </div>

  <div class="tabelEvents">
  <table id="eventList" class="tabel" border="1">
  <tr><th>Datum</th><th>Titel</th><th>Auteur</th></tr>
  </table>
  </div>

   <div id="home2">
    <form name="input" action="" method="get">
     <a href="welkom.html"><img src="home.png" alt="Home" /></a>
    </form>
   </div>

   <div id="terug2">
    <form name="input" action="" method="get">
     <a href="bekijken.html"><img id="btnterug" src="vorige.png" alt="Vorige" /></a>
    </form>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```